# Jaspersoft Server crashes when two instances of the same subreport are included in a report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, subreport

I've been working with Jasper Studio for a few weeks now and built a some reports (some include subreports) that look very nice and work perfectly in preview mode.
Now I'd like to deploy them on JasperServer and this is where I'm facing my problem.
I managed to reproduce it with a simple report and a subreport included twice.

In this example report the idea is simple: I have:
- a subreport that takes one parameter
- a main report that includes two instances of this subreport, and passes them two different values as parameter.

The result:
- When I include only one instance of the subreport, it works perfectly
- When I include it twice (the parameter value does not matter), the execution on jasperserver crashes with the following error :

**Error filling report
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : tests/srvtest/footersub.jasper**

I deploy the report ant its subreport with the "publish" button in Jasper Studio.
I don't think it's a subreport path issue because with only one instance of it, it's ok. It's only when I put 2 or more instances of the subreport in the main report that the server crashes...

It doesn't change the behaviour if I hardcode the parameter value or if I transmit it from the main report's parameters.

Do you have an idea?

I'm running on Windows 7, with Jasper server v.6.0.1 and JasperStudio 6.0.4

Many thanks for your help,

Nico

Here are the source files of the subreport and the report. Both are stand-alone, they can be run without a data source.
Main report :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.4.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.4  -->
<!-- 2015-05-21T16:21:32 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="rpt" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ef29a4c5-cefe-4c49-8626-ec7341c9cbab">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="agora_oracle"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://localhost:8585/jasperserver/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="joeuser|jasperadmin"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/reports/Tests/rpt_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/Tests/rpt"/>
    <parameter name="sub1" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["sub 1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="sub2" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["sub 2"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select * from mgusers]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="156" y="0" width="243" height="30" uuid="86f84720-da73-442d-84d3-2c04ea97483a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="18"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Rapport de test]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="180" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="0" y="12" width="555" height="28" uuid="890bcdb4-97e8-465a-bee5-a9ef52bc136b"/>
                <subreportParameter name="nom">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["tests/srvtest/footersub.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport runToBottom="true">
                <reportElement x="1" y="43" width="555" height="28" uuid="2fdad4ca-5e84-4533-b808-0b95d10aae68"/>
                <subreportParameter name="nom">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{sub2}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["tests/srvtest/footersub.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

Sub report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.4.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.4  -->
<!-- 2015-05-21T16:19:46 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="footersub" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="094a5941-d53b-4f31-a776-a68a3800223c">
    <parameter name="nom" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Mon nom"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <summary>
        <band height="21">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="150" y="1" width="235" height="20" uuid="b73f03fe-439f-4d1f-b301-8d0f9fa7a799"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Footer " + $P{nom}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

That stinks. Try this.
Before you upload your report to the server click the source tab at the bottom in JSS.

Change each sub report reference to be ![CDATA["repo:footersub.jrxml"]]

I created a report and used an existing sub report to accomplish exactly what you are trying to do with these changes, but my report was an actual resource on the master report.

It could be that you cannot reference a sub report twice from another location in the repo. I will try that next.